# Docker image larger than its filesystem

Tags: docker, containers

I have a docker image that I built from several layers and a debian:jessie base image that I'm working on making smaller. I added a cleanup layer than does `apt-get remove` a bunch of packages and deletes files from the filesystem. When I run the resulting image and do `du -h` inside it I can see it's about `1.3GB`. However, when I look at the image size in `docker images`, it's more than `2.2GB`, which is the size of the image before the cleanup layer. Why is the final image not getting smaller?

Comment: How are you cleaning ? Cleaning have to be in the same command than the thing you want to clean (ex : if you install curl to download something, you have to download it in the same run then remove curl). Else, you will have a lighter running container but image will not be cleaned. (layer rules)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't have a cleanup layer - the [Union File System](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/glossary/#union-file-system) doesn't work like that. If files exist in layer 1, and you delete them in layer 2, all Docker does when you run the container is hide the deleted files. Once files are saved into an image layer, they can't be removed from that layer.

You can try using the [Docker squash](https://github.com/jwilder/docker-squash) tool to reduce the final image size, or rework your Dockerfiles in line with [Titouan Freville](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5043876/titouan-freville)'s comment - do all the APT commands in one RUN statement (update, install remove). That way when the image layer is saved, the files have already been cleaned up.